# How to compare between a date string and a date

Tags: php, string, date

I have a field in my SQL. Example:

```
field : expireddate      type  : varchar (10)
```

It will contain data such as $expireddate = 31/08/2014  and I will compare it with today's date

```
$today = date("d/m/Y"); 

if ($query['expireddate']<$today){
    echo 'expired date';
}
else
{
    echo 'uptodate';
}
```

but it is not working. I tried to convert string to date:

```
$expireddate=strtotime('d/m/Y','$query[expireddate]')
```

but it is still not working.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Of course this is not working, because strings are compared character-by-character from left to right, and `dd/mm/yyyy` is not a “sortable” format in that regard – you would need something like `yyyy/mm/dd`. But it would be better to not store dates as text in the first place, but use one of the designated types your DBMS offers for that … and then do that comparison inside the query already, instead afterwards in (what looks like) PHP.

Answer (score 0):

However, if you just replace "/" with "-" it will work fine.

```
<?php
$expireddate = "31/08/2014";
$today = date("d/m/Y"); 

$expireddate=strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $expireddate));
$today=strtotime(str_replace('/', '-', $today));

if ($expireddate<$today){
    echo 'expired date';
}
else
{
    echo 'uptodate';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to replace characters in your string or use `strtotime()` which is not recommended for date math. PHP has tools built in designed to make this sort of thing easy.

You should use [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) objects as they are comparable. One issue you will have, though, is your date format is not standard. When using `/` as a separator PHP will assume MM/DD/YYYY format. So you will need to use [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to overcome this.

```
$today   = new DateTime();
$expires = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $query['expireddate']);

if ($expires < $today){
    echo 'expired date';
}
else {
    echo 'uptodate';
}
```

Advice: don't store your dates as strings in your database. Even more importantly, don't store them in non-standard formats. It's *trivial* to transform a date into any format you want when querying the database plus you can take advantage of all your database's date functionality which you can't do when they are strings (at least not without having to manipulate those strings first which makes things a lot more complicated).